# Android camera HAL3

Tags: android, android-camera, hal

I am learning camera HAL3 requirements for the latest version of Android and trying to understand how RAW output should be implemented. Specifically Android requires the HAL to provide a RAW image from the sensor to the application for future processing.

In the case of HDR processing when short image is stitched together with long exposure image we actually have two RAWs instead of one.

**So the question is how to return two RAWs (short and long) properly on request via the callback to the application?**

Please help me to understand it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean camera raw data with android follow?

First, you AP should be support capture two channel raw data. With Qualcomm, we should bypass ISP instead of handled by ISP. In this way you could get raw data or YUV(get Y)

Second, android framework has provided V3/HAL3 to us. You can research carefully.